# changing a const char *str1 = "abc"

Tags: c, string, char

Is this good practice? The code compiles and runs but I wonder if this is a good practice to emulate
In C code,

1. we write `const char *str1 = "abc";`
2. then later, lets say there is a pointer variable `char *str2` that points to dynamically allocated memory
3. and then we do `str1 = str2` so now both `str1` and `str2` point to dynamically allocated memory

So now we have lost track of any pointer to `"abc"`. Though in this code, we may not need it but I wonder what is the best recommended way to handle these.

The overall problem is that we need a string that initially is declared to abc and later dependent on user input, we may want to use the string supplied by the user.

Comment: I'm no neckbeard-wearing developer, but why would anyone change anything denoted as constant, ever?

Comment: @GrantThomas but he's not changing anything marked const. The 'const' qualifier in the declaration refers to what str1 points to, not str1 itself.

Comment: @Clyde Well, yes, but my statement still stands, whether you're talking about the thing or the thing's thing. It appears that one, the developer, would want it to be constant.

Comment: @GrantThomas Without wanting to be argumentative, your statement is reasonable in itself, but completely orthogonal to the question.

Comment: @GrantThomas Even if it is planned to change the pointer later on, it would be incorrect to *not* declare it as pointer to const char, if it was to be initialised with a pointer to an array of const chars, which is what a constant string is.

Comment: @GrantThomas Certain pedantic compilers throw this warning if you leave it out:    x.c:
     1: char * p = "abc";
                 ^ (359) illegal conversion between pointer types (warning)
pointer to const unsigned char -> pointer to unsigned char

Comment: @Clyde: The only compilers that give a warning for this that I know of are C++ compilers. If your C compiler says it's illegal to convert a string literal to a `char *`, it's not compliant: string literals are not const in C. String literals are const in C++ however.

Comment: @GrantThomas: If the developer wanted both the data and the pointer to be constant, he should declare is as `const char * const`.

Comment: @netcoder It's a warning. A very pertinent one, since according to ISO/IEC 9899:1999 with respect to the arrays implementing string literals "If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is undefined." It's therefore good practice to refer to string literals only with pointers that don't allow modification of the target. So not illegal, just dangerous.

Comment: @Clyde: Still, you're refering to C++ compilers, because a compliant C compiler would never tell you it's illegal. The standard states *"For character string literals, the array elements have type `char`"* in C,  while it states *"An ordinary string literal has type 'array of n `const char`'"* in C++. Granted, it can be dangerous to leave out the const qualifier, but it is not incorrect as per the standard.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24562/discussion-between-clyde-and-netcoder)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's absolutely fine. `const char *str1` means "a pointer that can be modified, to character data that cannot be modified (through this pointer)".

So, you can point `str1` at any string you like, and it makes sense to "reseat" it to point at different strings at different times.

Obviously if your code is complicated enough, you can make it difficult for a reader to work out what the variable currently contains, but that's true of all variables. For example you want to be careful with pointers that sometimes point at string literals and sometimes point at dynamically-allocated memory, because it might not always be clear whether the pointer should be `free`ed.

If you wanted `str1` to always point at the same string, you would define it `const char * const str1` (or `char const *const str1` in order to make the position of the `const` always consistent). That's not what you want in this case, and the fact that you haven't declared `str1` const indicates as much to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

Losing the pointer to the string literal will not lead to memory leak, so what you do is safe in that aspect.

Answer (score 1):

The string literal `"abc"` is not dynamically allocated, so there is nothing that can leak in this situation.

String literals are a part of the "program image" that gets loaded into memory at startup by the executable loader of the operating system. The space that this image occupies is reclaimed by the operating system once the process is over. Of course this is not quite accurate since there are techniques like demand paging and copy-on-write, but they are irrelevant for that case.

It would be a problem if you didn't put `const` in that definition. The latter would allow you to attempt to modify a piece of memory which is usually stored in a read-only area of the process, so undefined behaviour would manifest.